# Free/delete a char* causes an invalid heap pointer assertion failure

Tags: dll, interop, c++-cli, memory-management

I have a chunk of code that I'm using to get the UNC path of a mapped drive in a CLR DLL, but when I'm freeing memory at the end, a char array causes an invalid heap pointer assertion failure, and I'm assuming it has to do with it being allocated by InteropServices, but I want to make sure it doesn't turn into a memory leak as this function gets called repeatedly.

Code:

```cpp
DWORD MAX_DEVICE_LENGTH = 1000;
TCHAR* szDeviceName = new TCHAR[MAX_DEVICE_LENGTH];
memset(szDeviceName, '\0', MAX_DEVICE_LENGTH); 
DWORD dwResult; 


char* charpath = (char*)   (void*)System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(path->Substring(0,2));
wchar_t* tpath = new wchar_t[MAX_DEVICE_LENGTH];

memset(tpath, '\0', MAX_DEVICE_LENGTH);

DWORD dwNum = MultiByteToWideChar (CP_ACP, 0, charpath, -1, NULL, 0);
MultiByteToWideChar (CP_ACP, 0, charpath, -1, tpath, dwNum );


dwResult = WNetGetConnection(
    tpath,
    szDeviceName, &MAX_DEVICE_LENGTH); 

System::String ^ str = gcnew System::String(szDeviceName);

str += path->Substring(2, path->Length-2);

delete(szDeviceName);
free(charpath); //This is where it assert-fails
delete(tpath);

return str;
```

It's probably something basic about memory de-allocation that I don't understand, but either way it's worth figuring out. If it helps, if I skip over that line tpath deletes fine, but if the charpath assertion fails then tpath will fail as well.

Comment: Have you profiled this?  Do you know there's a memory leak?

Comment: `memset(tpath, '\0', MAX_DEVICE_ LENGTH);` only initialises half the array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relevant comment on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx) is

> StringToHGlobalAnsi is useful for custom marshaling or when mixing
>   managed and unmanaged code. Because this method allocates the
>   unmanaged memory required for a string, always free the memory by
>   calling FreeHGlobal. StringToHGlobalAnsi provides the opposite
>   functionality of Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi.

So, no delete/free but `FreeHGlobal`.

Comment: @its don't change the question. Accept the answer.

Comment: In C++, you probably want [`GlobalFree`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366579.aspx).  But definitely allocator and deallocator MUST match.

Answer (score 5):

For `szDeviceName` and `tpath` use `delete[]` instead of `delete`. `[]` version is for arrays and non-`[]`  version is for single objects.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx), you should be freeing the memory with [`FreeHGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is just wrong:

```
free(charpath);
```

Since `charpath` was allocated by `StringToHGlobalAnsi` you should call `FreeHGlobal`. Like this:

```
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(charpath));
```